# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).slideme is not a function

Tags: jquery

I am creating a slideshow with slideme JQuery plugin. I tried the code at a blank document, it worked and then I copy pasted it into my webpage document. But I get this error from google chrome inspect element : `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).slideme` is not a function

This is my **head** :

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Inconsolata' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato&subset=latin,latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'

<script src="jquery.slideme2.js"></script>
<link href="slideme.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#demo').slideme({autoslide:true,arrows:true,loop:true,transition:"zoom"});
    });
</script>
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicon.ico"/>
<title>DEEAN Consulting Group</title>
```

and this is the **body**

```
        <div id="demo">
        <ul class="slideme">
        <!-- Class "slideme" is mandatatory! -->
        <li><img src="images/1.jpg"/></li>
        <li><img src="images/3.jpg"/></li>
        <li><img src="images/4.jpg" /></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Sanity check - are the jquery, jquery.slideme2.js etc files being loaded successfully (check the Network tab in Dev Tools)?

Comment: Looks like it can't find "jquery.slideme2.js" with "<script src="jquery.slideme2.js"></script>". Check your file structure to see if it links to the right path.

Comment: found the error. thanks for help anyway

Answer (score 0):

got the error, there was no ending > in one of the links to google fonts

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato&subset=latin,latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'
```